# Call to undefined relationship [cities] on model [App\Models\Municipal_district]

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

**City.php**

```
public function municipal_districts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Municipal_district');
}
```

**Municipal_district.php**

```
public function province()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\City', 'city_id');
}
```

Where can be wrong?

Comment: Where is cities() relationship?

Comment: In Municipal_district.php`public function cities()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\City', 'city_id');
    }
`

Comment: Is it in the Municipal_district.php ?

Comment: yes. One City has many municipal_districts

Comment: I solved it, thanks @MortezaRajabi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

City Model

```
public function municipal_districts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Municipal_district');
}
```

Municipal_district Model

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\City', 'city_id');
}
```

And I don't knwo about cities() relationship here!

City has many ditricts and District belongs to one city. So, What is the cities() here?

Comment: I failed this function `public function province()` isn't proviice() but is city()